# Parameter as ":any" in a guard type

Tags: typescript, typeguards

Been getting into Typescript & very much at the point where I'm implementing a project as type safe as possible. Just been experimenting with Type Guards and was wondering if I could make this Type Guard anymore type safe.

Purely asking as any implementation of `any` feels hacky.

**Explanation**

`name_split`

An `array` of `strings` that may or may not be property names of the current class or a property name within an `object` of that class

`currVal`

A property name of the `prevVal` variable which may be an `object` or `null` (first run)

`prevVal`

Reference of `this` or an object inside of `this` (or deeper), may also be null (first run)

```
return name_split?.reduce((prevVal: any, currVal: string) => {

    currVal = currVal === 'initial' ? `_${currVal}` : currVal;

    if (prevVal) return prevVal[currVal];

    if (!Guards.isKeyOf<this>(this, currVal)) return prevVal;

    return this[currVal];
}, null) || data;
```

Now I was running into an issue where if I didn't have my `Guards.isKeyOf` in place aka

```
return name_split?.reduce((prevVal: any, currVal: string) => {

     currVal = currVal === 'initial' ? `_${currVal}` : currVal;

     if (prevVal) return prevVal[currVal];

     return this[currVal];
}, null) || data;
```

The return statement would be invalid as `currVal` has a type of string instead of the property type that the `this` object has aka `options` or `commands`

Thus I implemented this

```
export function isKeyOf<A>(ref: A, input: any): input is keyof A {

    return !!ref[(input as keyof A)];
}
```

and added as such

```
return name_split?.reduce((prevVal: any, currVal: string) => {

    currVal = currVal === 'initial' ? `_${currVal}` : currVal;

    if (prevVal) return prevVal[currVal];

    if (!Guards.isKeyOf<this>(this, currVal)) return prevVal;

    return this[currVal];
}, null) || data;
```

Which resolves the issue, however `input: any` gives me a "hacky" vibe, is there a method I can implement to increase the type safety?

Comment: The whole point of type guards is that they delegate compile-time type safety to the runtime. There's nothing wrong with using `any` in a type guard because **that's what they're built to do.**

Comment: `!!ref[(input as keyof A)];` only checks if the key *currently exists* on the object and if its value is truthy. However, it would fail with `ref = { a: 0 }` when checking for `"a"` or when checking for `b` that *could* exist (e.g., the type of `ref` is `{a: number, b?: number}`). You can use `input in ref` to check if the key exists regardless of its value but it is still only valid for anything currently on the object, not what is allowed to be on the object. If that's acceptable, I'd advise going with `in`.

Comment: As for `input: any` - you don't REALLY allow anything there, right? For example, a boolean or `null` are not valid keys for an objects (the *strings*, "true" or "null" are, however). An object's key is usually typed as `string | number | symbol` but even typing it as `string` is quite OK. Symbols are rare and you can ignore them in many cases while numbers are really just converted to strings anyway. And objects with numeric keys are also rare (aside from arrays and array-likes).

Comment: @VLAZ I've now implemented as such.

`export function isKeyOf<A>(input: any, ref: A): input is keyof A { return input in ref; }`
&
`if (!Guards.isKeyOf<this>(currVal, this)) return prevVal;`

it works. Feel free to add as an answer and I'll tick.

@Aplet123 I was actually thinking about it at the time of posting that the input is resolved from `any` to a specific anyway. Thanks for verifying this.

`